# How to properly merge CEF 2623 into 2454-based project

Tags: chromium-embedded

I have a CEF-2454-based project that I wish to upgrade to 2623. However, I have made some changes to libcef needed for the project and I want to incorporate all changes made in 2623 without discarding my own changes. This raises me some questions:

- What `git merge` strategy should I employ?
- Can I build in my old 2454 directory, or I need to merge then build from scratch?
- Should I merge 2526 then 2623, or I can directly merge 2623?

What is the proper way to incorporate a new CEF release into my own project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical way is to merge *your* changes onto new CEF version. Unfortunately all other methods are more difficult.

You can try to take a diff between your changes and original CEF 2454, and try to apply that patch on 2623.